# Graph road complexity

Tags: java, graph, time-complexity

I need to make an algorithm that verifies if there is a road from the node `x` to the node `y` in a graph. The edges in the graph have a series of rights attached to them (like `r, w, e`, etc.). My algorithm need to have `|e| + |v|` complexity. I can only go through nodes whose edge with the node before them has a certain set of rights given as a parameter.

For example, if I have a set of rights: `r, w, e, g` and I distribute these rights randomly on the edges, and I give as a parameter for my search method the set of rights: `e, g`, I can only go through nodes whose edges has the rights `e,g`.

How can I do this in `|e| + |v|` time complexity if DFS algorithm has is I recall correctly `|e| + |v|` time complexity and I also need to search if the edges have the desired set of rights, which I think adds to the complexity.

Comment: The "desired set of rights" should be the edge/node property so when you preform DFS you choose only eligible edges (you don't have to "check" eligibility if its a property) the lookup is O(1) to check if an edge is eligible so it shouldn't change the magnitude of the run-time

Comment: I fear I don't understand.Let's say I have the set B={r,w,e,g}.Every edge can have any kind of subset from the set B.i get as a parameter the set a={r,w}.When I do DFS I must check the edge to see if the edge ahs the set a.That means that I must compare 2 lists.How can I do that to be O(1) complexity ?

Comment: `for(Edge e: edges){ if(e.r && e.w){...` won't change the run time. If you had a list of N properties to check where `N = |V|` for example, then, indeed,  it would change the run-time complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply [breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) (unlike DFS, it will find the shortest path) modifying it slightly to take into account only nodes which have the required rights.

Here is the pseudo-code, I'm sure you can translate it to Java:

```
procedure BFS(G,v):
        create a queue Q
        create a set V
        enqueue v onto Q
        add v to V
        while Q is not empty:
                t ‹ Q.dequeue()
                if t is what we are looking for:
                        return t
             for all edges e in G.adjacentEdges(t) do
                     u ‹ G.adjacentVertex(t,e)
                     if u is not in V and t.hasRights(allowedRights):
                                add u to V
                                enqueue u onto Q
     return none
```

It differs from the one on Wikipedia only by checking the `t.hasRights(allowedRights)` condition.

Using Java [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html), checking a set of rights can be easily done in O(1) time, adding nothing to E+V complexity of the BFS algorithm (assuming number of available rights is constant).

In each node you store a set of rights, and then check if all required rights are in the set ([HashSet.contains(Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) is O(1)).

Also, you can represent your rights as `enum` and use [EnumSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) to store the right sets. EnumSet is implemented as bit vectors and so is as fast as you can get with sets.

Comment: You don't answer the question! Using BFS or DFS doesn't matter for the run-time, it'll remain `|E|+|V|`

Comment: I believe I did answer the question. Complexity is alright and I proposed BFS just because it finds the shortest path.

Comment: Read his question again, pay close attention to the last paragraph! The fact that you posted some pseudo-code doesn't make your answer a good one!

Comment: "How can I do this in e+v complexity" -- algorithm in my answer has E+V complexity. Ah, okay, checking the set of rights. I will update in a minute.

Comment: Nice!!! you quote only the first part of the sentence :))) DFS has the same complexity as BFS - which means that you actually **didn't** answer his question

Comment: The thing was that aside DFS or BFS which have e+v complexity I also need to compare 2 lists at every edge to see if the edge has the desired set of rights.This adds to the complexity because comparing 2 lists can not be made in o(1) complexity.Thank you for the answers and comment.Now I must find another way,beside lists,to represent the rights so that I get v+e complexity

Comment: I have updated my answer, sorry for not reading the question carefully enough.

Comment: I read that HashSet in worst case scenario has O(N) complexity and usually has O(1) complexity.

Comment: If you store objects with properly written hashCode methods (e.g. Strings or numbers that could serve you for representing the rights), then it will be O(1). Also, see the last paragraph of my answer (updated).